# Not quite understanding how passing a value to next() works with yield in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, iterator, yield

The Mozilla Developer Network has the following example of passing a value to `next()` and how it's captured by `yield`:

```
function* fibonacci() {
  let current = 0;
  let next = 1;
  while (true) {
    let reset = yield current;
    [current, next] = [next, next + current];
    if (reset) {
        current = 0;
        next = 1;
    }
  }
}

const sequence = fibonacci();
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 0
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 3
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 5
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 8
console.log(sequence.next(true).value); // 0
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
```

What I'm confused about is the `let reset = yield current;` line.  I understand that `current` will receive the value passed into `next()`.  What I *don't* understand is why the `if (reset) { /* ... */ }` conditional won't evaluate to true once `current` is any value greater than 1.

It seems like the `let reset = yield current;` line is only evaluated if a value is passed into `next()`, but I'm not sure that's actually the case, let alone why it would be the case if so.  The MDN docs gloss over what's actually going on here.

Further explanation would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Put another way, what does `let reset = yield current;` mean when a value is NOT passed into `next()`? Because `current` is still increasing in value with each run of the loop. Is the assignment simply not happening?

Comment: When you call `next()` with a parameter, it becomes the return value of `yield`. So when you call `next(true)` it sets `reset` to `true`.

Comment: “You can also send a value with next(value) into the generator. 'step' evaluates as a return value” https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield#using_yield

Comment: I don't think I'm being clear... what does `let reset = yield current;` mean when a value is NOT passed into `next()`?  Because `current` is still increasing in value with each run of the loop.  Is the assignment simply not happening?

Comment: Returned, but not assigned to `reset`?

Comment: When no argument is passed into `next()`, the return value is undefined. When you pass `true` as `next(true)`, then it returns `true`, which passes the if check. Do a console log of `reset` and you will see.

Comment: That's not true, though, as `next()` returns an object with the form of `{value: /* value of the next iterated item */, done: /* a boolean that's false unless the last iterable item has been reached */}`.  See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/generator/next

Comment: I guess my confusion comes from the assignment.  It seems like it should be 'working' (for lack of a better term) regardless of whether or not a value has been passed into `next();`

Comment: That `reset` should be receiving a value every time through the loop

Comment: @MajorProductions `.next()` is the same as `.next(undefined)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function* fibonacci() {
  let current = 0;
  let next = 1;
  while (true) {
    let reset = yield current;
    console.log('reset value', reset);
    [current, next] = [next, next + current];
    if (reset) {
        current = 0;
        next = 1;
    }
  }
}

const sequence = fibonacci();
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 0
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 3
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 5
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 8
console.log(sequence.next(true).value); // 0
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 1
console.log(sequence.next().value);     // 2
```

Using nothing but console log.  We can see the reset variable gets the value of undefined when nothing is passed to next() and gets the value passed to next otherwise.
You are allowed to in javascript, assign the value `undefined` to a variable, that's all that's happening here.

I don't like when they use such irrelevant examples for code.  With no real life context it's difficult to understand this or why you would ever use it.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer to provide more detail/clarity for anyone else who may be as stumped as I was.  The other key aspect to this seemingly weird behavior is to remember that `yield` pauses the generator's execution until `next()` is called again.  The following code (a slightly modified version of MDN example code found here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) illustrates this (pay particular attention to when the variable `step` has a value):

```
function* counter(value) {
 let step;

 while (true) {
   step = yield ++value;
   console.log(`step = ${step}, value = ${value}`);

   if (step) {
     value += step;
   }
 }
}

const generatorFunc = counter(0);
console.log(generatorFunc.next().value);   
console.log(generatorFunc.next().value);   
console.log(generatorFunc.next().value);   
console.log(generatorFunc.next(10).value); 
console.log(generatorFunc.next().value);   
console.log(generatorFunc.next(10).value);
```

The output:

```
1
"step = undefined, value = 1"
2
"step = undefined, value = 2"
3
"step = 10, value = 3"
14
"step = undefined, value = 14"
15
"step = 10, value = 15"
26
```